# Powershell Find String Between Characters and Replace

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, hashtable

In **Powershell** script, I have **Hashtable** contains personal information. The hashtable looks like

```
{first = "James", last = "Brown", phone = "12345"...}
```

Using this hashtable, I would like to replace strings in template text file. For each string matches **@key@** format, I want to replace this string to **value** that correspond to key in hashtable. Here is a sample input and output:

input.txt

```
My first name is @first@ and last name is @last@. 
Call me at @phone@
```

output.txt

```
My first name is James and last name is Brown. 
Call me at 12345
```

Could you advise me **how to return "key" string between "@"s**  so I can find their value for the string replacement function? Any other ideas for this problem is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with pure regex, but for the sake of readability, I like doing this as more code than regex:

```poweshell
$tmpl = 'My first name is @first@ and last name is @last@. 
Call me at @phone@'

$h = @{
    first = "James"
    last = "Brown"
    phone = "12345"
}

$new = $tmpl

foreach ($key in $h.Keys) {
    $escKey = [Regex]::Escape($key)
    $new = $new -replace "@$escKey@", $h[$key]
}

$new
```

### Explanation

`$tmpl` contains the template string.

`$h` is the hashtable.

`$new` will contain the replaced string.

1. We enumerate through each of the keys in the hash.
2. We store a regex escaped version of the key in `$escKey`.
3. We replace `$escKey` surrounded by `@` characters with the hashtable lookup for the particular key.

One of the nice things about doing this is that you can change your hashtable and your template, and never have to update the regex. It will also gracefully handle the cases where a key has no corresponding replacable section in the template (and vice-versa).

Comment: Works Perfect. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template using an expandable (double-quoted) here-string:

```
$Template = @"
My first name is $($hash.first) and last name is $($hash.last). 
Call me at $($hash.phone)
"@

$hash = @{first = "James"; last = "Brown"; phone = "12345"}

$Template

My first name is James and last name is Brown. 
Call me at 12345
```